How to Serialize and read metadata in Dask Dataframe
I'm trying to pre-compute dask divisions and categories for certain columns in dask dataframe, then save data as new dataframe and reuse it down the road.
Issue I encountered is that when I read dataframe back it there misses  divisions and categories.
This is the snippet:
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_parquet('filename')
cat_columns= ['state', ...] 
df= df.categorize(columns= cat_columns)
df = df.set_index('rn', drop=True, sorted=True, npartitions=None, divisions=None, sort=False)
df = df.persist(scheduler='single-threaded')
df.to_parquet('filename2',write_metadata_file=True, write_index=True, compute=True)

df2= dd.read_parquet('filename2')

df2.divisions 
#above results in all None

df2.state.cat.categories  
#above results :  AttributeNotImplementedError: `df.column.cat.categories` with unknown categories is not supported.  

My question is what am I doing wrong here, is it saving a dataframe, loading or both?

Do you mind to read [ask] and add a [mcve]?
